# Im trying to get all the Mondays from today to a certain date...this query works until I add the dayofweek function to it, and then it returns no rows

Tags: mysql

set @i = -1;
select adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 day) AS ndate, DAYNAME(adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL @i day)) DAYN, dayofweek(adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL @i day)) daynu FROM PayrollDates where dayofweek(adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL @i day)) > 4 and adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL @i-1 day) < '2018-03-01'

Comment: **  should list dates from today to 2018-03-01   that are Thurs, Fri, or Sat.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with sql for this